# related to classification of groups of order 8

Tags: group-theory

Consider a group $G$ of order 8. Let $y \in G$ have order 4. Put $H=\{1,y,y^2,y^3\}$ and $x \in G-H$

Need to:

(i)show $H \triangleleft G$ and $x^2 \in H$

(ii) list possibilities for $x^2$

(iii) list possibilities for $xyx^{-1}$

I've shown that $H \triangleleft G$ but literally have no idea about the rest...Can someone give a little help please?

Edit: For (iii), since $H \triangleleft G$,  $xyx^{-1} \in H, {\forall} y \in H, \forall x \in G$

Edit 2: the aim of the question is to use the possibilities for $x^2$ (labelled $P_1,...,P_n$) and the possibilities for $xyx^{-1}$ (labelled $Q_1,...,Q_m$), look at each $(P_i,Q_j)$ and show that G is isomorphic to one of: $C_8, C_4 \times C_2, D_8, Q_8$

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few reflections:

(i) The quotient $G/H$ is a group of order $2$, hence $x^2H=H$.

(ii) The order of $x^2$ is a divisor of the order of $x$, and $x^2$ lies in $H$, hence its order is $1,2$ or $4$.

- If $x^2$ has order $4$, then $x$ has order $8$ and $G$  is cyclic, isomorphic with $\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$.
- If $x^2$ has order $2$, then $x^2=y^2$.

(iii) $xyx^{-1}$ is a conjugate of $y$, hence is of order $4$. Thus

- either  $xyx^{-1}=y$, which implies $xy=yx$ so $G$ is abelian.
- or   $xyx^{-1}=y^3$.